# How to generate and display a QR Code in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've found documentation for generating barcodes in angular and ionic 1, but I need to generate one in an Ionic 2 project.

Answer (score 0):

Try the JsBarcode project. There is an wrapper for angular 1. I used the instructions located in this issue to get it working on angular 2.

https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/issues/105

Here's the sparknotes:

- Install the plugin with NPM `npm install jsbarcode --save`.
- Import the library in your controller `import JsBarcode from 'jsbarcode';`
- Create an empty object to hold your barcode `<svg #barcode id="barcode"></svg>`
- Generate the barcode:

Use the following code to generate the barcode.

```
 @ViewChild('barcode') barcode: ElementRef;
    ngAfterViewInit() {
       JsBarcode(this.barcode.nativeElement, '12345');
    }
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately JsBarcode is a barcode (one dimensional code) generator, but the question asked for a QR-code (two dimensional code) generator

Answer (score 0):

Install the following NPM package to create QR codes with just a few lines of code.

> ngx-qrcode2

For reference on generation and scanning of QR Code, go through the following link-

https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-qr-code-generator-reader/