# Ionic 3 Create 2D barcode instead of QR code

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I want to create a barcode using member information. I use @ ionic-native / barcode-scanner as an add-on.
I am generating a QR code with the code fragment shown below.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-kartbilgileri',
  templateUrl: 'kartbilgileri.html',
})
export class KartbilgileriPage {
  UYEID : string = window.localStorage.getItem("auth_key");
  GOSTER;
  constructor(public barcode : BarcodeScanner, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.barkodOlustur();
  }
  barkodOlustur(){
    this.barcode.encode(this.barcode.Encode.TEXT_TYPE,this.UYEID).then((encodedData) => {
      this.GOSTER = encodedData.text;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("Error occured : " + err);
    });    
  }
}
```

How can I create a 2D barcode instead of this QR code that I created?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to the problem. I used JsBarcode. 
https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/issues/105
I used this link for the installation.
[How to generate and display a QR Code in ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141618/how-to-generate-and-display-a-qr-code-in-ionic-2)

- Install the plugin with NPM npm install jsbarcode --save.
- Import the library in your controller import JsBarcode from 'jsbarcode';
- Create an empty object to hold your barcode

```html
<svg #barcode id="barcode"></svg>
```

```js
@ViewChild('barcode') barcode: ElementRef;
    ngAfterViewInit() {
       JsBarcode(this.barcode.nativeElement, window.localStorage.getItem("auth_key"));
    }
```